# tabs and fragments android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem. 
I just created an app in which I can navigate through tabs and sections. 
How can i tell eclipse to load me the "main.xml" layout and not to create a new Linear layout with a text view? 
Is it possible guys?

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class FirstTabFragment extends Fragment
{

private Activity activity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.activity = getActivity();


    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

    TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
    textView.setText("This is a sample fragment. I am programmatically added");
    linearLayout.addView(textView);

    return linearLayout;
}
    }
```

My main.xml code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="@drawable/screenshot1" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: and your main.xml content is ?

Comment: check the edited one plz ... and thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container,false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService("layout_inflater");
TextView textView = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null);
```